# Tangent cone of affine line at the origin

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homogeneous-equation, affine-varieties

I am trying to calculate the tangent cone of $\mathbb{A}^1$ at the point $Q=1$. To do that, I first want to calculate the tangent cone at the origin, and then "translate back".

Here is the definition that I use. For an affine variety $V= \text{Specm }k[X_1,\ldots X_n]/\mathfrak{a}$ over an algebraically closed field $k$, we can define the ideal $\mathfrak{a}_* =\{f_*:f\in\mathfrak{a}\}$ where, for $f\in k[X_1,\ldots X_n]$, $f_*$ is the homogeneous part of $f$ of lowest degree. The tangent cone at the origin is defined as the $k$-algebra $k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/\mathfrak{a}_*$.

I know that $\mathbb{A}^1$ is defined by the polynomial $0$. Does this not mean that $\mathfrak{a}_*=(0)$? Then we would have that the tangent cone at the origin is equal to $k[X]$.

If this is the tangent cone at the origin, then something tells me that the tangent cone at $Q$ must be $k[Y]/(Y-1)$. However, I don't entirely see why. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The image of the zero ideal under any automorphism of an integral domain is still the zero ideal.

Comment: So you are confirming that $\mathfrak{a}_*=(0)$?

Comment: Yes, $\mathfrak{a}_*=0$. On the other hand, your final conclusion that the tangent cone is $k[Y]/(Y-1)$ is wrong - the image of $(0)$ under the automorphism $X\mapsto Y-1$ is still $(0)$.

Comment: I see, so I don't understand how I should "translate" the tangent cone at the origin to the tangent cone at $Q$. Could you help me with that? Do you know what the tangent cone should be?

Comment: What is your definition of the tangent cone at a point which is *not* the origin?

Comment: @ronno I don't have a definition of a tangent cone at a point which is not the origin. The author that I am reading (Milne) keeps it vague by saying that one should "translate" to get the tangent cone at any other point... Do you have a definition for me?

Comment: For any $a \in k^n$, $x \mapsto x + a$ is a *translation* of $\mathbb{A}^n$. The corresponding algebra map (in the reverse direction) is $X_i \mapsto X_i + a_i$.